# How to prevent NavigationView from affecting subviews

Tags: list, swiftui, navigationview

I'd like to use a NavigationView for several reasons but when I wrap my view hierarchy in a NavigationView, things get messed up. Screen 1 shows the effect i'm after but the NavigationView has not been added yet.  The code for screen 1 is:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing:0) {
            Text("Text Above List")
                .frame(width: 375, height: 44)
                    .background(Color.gray)
            List() {
                Text("Row 1")
                Text("Row 2")
                Text("Row 3")
                Text("Row 4")
                Text("Row 5")
              }
         }
    }
 }
```

By wrapping in a NavigationView the result is screen 2.  Code for screen 2 is:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing:0) {
                Text("Text Above List")
                    .frame(width: 375, height: 44)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                List() {
                    Text("Row 1")
                    Text("Row 2")
                    Text("Row 3")
                    Text("Row 4")
                    Text("Row 5")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Then by adding ".listStyle(GroupedListStyle())" the result is screen 3 - which is close but no cigar.  I can't get rid of the space above the list but below the Text view above it.  The space is obviously the header view but I can't make it go away.  Code for screen 3 is:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing:0) {
                Text("Text Above List")
                    .frame(width: 375, height: 44)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                List() {
                    Text("Row 1")
                    Text("Row 2")
                    Text("Row 3")
                    Text("Row 4")
                    Text("Row 5")
                }
                .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  I have pulling my hair out over this for way too long.  Thanks.[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFHHB.jpg)

Tap the link "enter link description here" above, to see referenced screens.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you wanted plain list style

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(spacing:0) {
            Text("Text Above List")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 44)
                .background(Color.gray)
            List() {
                Text("Row 1")
                Text("Row 2")
                Text("Row 3")
                Text("Row 4")
                Text("Row 5")
            }.listStyle(PlainListStyle())     // << here !!
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh man, that was easy.... Thanks.  I made the assumption that since there are only two list styles available and setting to groupstyle clearly changed the appearance from not specifying the style that the default was plainstyle.  I'm often reminded about making assumptions... it bit me again.

Comment: You're welcome. In SwiftUI default style, if there are styles for that UI element, is platform-dependent, so no assumption at all - if you want something look persistently the style should be set explicitly, because if not, it might look different on iPad, even if it looks ok for you during testing on iPhone. Just in case. Btw... [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)